# Is subsequent cross validation on the same dataset biased?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I am training ML regression models to predict financial returns in a high frequency trading environment.

I have 1 time-series of intraday data for 40 years for 1 individual security at the moment.

I have run a cross-validation (keeping in mind the timestamp when creating the folds). However, after I obtain the best model and get predictions on the test data, even if my overall gross returns are positive, I am trading too often so trading costs eat all my profits giving me negative returns.

Thus, I need to find a way to select which days to trade based on the predicted returns. As I cannot apply the cross-sectional approach typical to low frequency strategies by only taking a position on the top X% of securities, I need to find a solution.

Instead of fixing an a-priori lower-bound threshold, and trading only when the predicted returns are higher (in absolute terms), I would like to add this as an extra parameter to focus only on the ost profitable trades based on my predictions.

I thought about the following approach:

- Run cross-validation to select the best hyperparameter combination, thus obtaining the best model.
- retrain the model with the best hyperparameters found in step 1 for each of the k folds (defined in the same way as before) creating a 'manual' cross-validation approach described as follows:

  1. For each fold, obtain the validation predicted returns, and after giving a list of lower-bound thresholds, compute the sharpe ratio (the scoring metric in my case) for each of the lower-bound thresholds.
  2. for each threshold, compute the mean of validation sharpe ratios across all k folds and pick the one with the highest value.

I was wondering whether this reasoning is correct from a ML perspective, or whether I am increasing significantly the bias and the second validation should be run on another held-out dataset.